# Present content like power point or impress

Tags: go, display, presentation

I want to build an application that displays the content that user types on the command prompt to the display like a presentation.
I am writing this application in golang. If there are existing libraries that I can use to do this great and if not would need direction how to approach solving this.
I did search on the internet for pointers but found none.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the present tool, it does a similar thing using flat files and might even be useful for you.

https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/present